# ROWCOUNT field in SYSTABLES table not updated after rows have been deleted

Tags: sqlbase

I use the ROWCOUNT field in SYSTABLES to get fast the rowcount of all my tables from a .NET App using Oledb (i don't want to use a query to get it becasue it takes too much time on big tables).

The problem is: after deleting rows from the table, that ROWCOUNT number in SYSTABLES is not updated. I tested some commands and even found that running ROWCOUNT TABLENAME in SqlTalk works and is very fast, but if i try to call that as a query from .NET using OLEDB it's returning nothing, sample code:

```
using (var connection = ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(NombreBaseModelo))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        foreach (Tabla ot in LstTables)
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000;
            cmd.CommandText = "ROWCOUNT " + ot.NAME;
            var sRet = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            ot.ROWCOUNT = int.Parse(sRet);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to tell SqlBase to update Rowcount for each table in systables?

Or as alternative, is there any way to make this code work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The systables.rowcount only gets updated when an update statistics is done, so it's not guaranteed to be accurate, until you execute 'Update Statistics on table ' + ot.NAME;
Then it is .

Probably not what you want when quickly counting rows.

Does your 'ot.NAME' variable have a table owner included ?   usually its 'SYSADM.'
Have you checked the value returned in 'sRet' , as maybe its 'int.Parse(sRet)' that is failing.
Otherwise create an index on the PK and execute a COUNT(*) . Should be as fast as ROWCOUNT anyway if the index is being used .

Alternatively, write a SQLBase function or stored proc that just executes the ROWCOUNT command natively and returns the correct count ( as per SQLTalk ), and call that from your , Net app

Comment: Thank you very much! That Update Statistics call is perfect. I'm making something like Sql Data compare that runs on SqlBase. Thank you again!